# Performance Tuning: Saving records exponentially grows every 500 records?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, query-performance

I wrote a class to read in a CSV file that houses 4k records, 72 col wide.  The 'read()' into the List takes literally a second, maybe...

Once I have successfully loaded up the List, I have the general flow for saving each object to the db;

```
foreach (var object in Objects)
{

  try{
      // check conditions
      // perform conversions on the data and assign to domain object.property
      //....
      //db.object.Add(object);
      //db.savechanges();

   }catch{

        //update log if the try fails   
   }
 }
```

Once the loop executes successfully, I call db.dispose();

I haven't built too many classes outside of the MVC controller structure because I'm new to this so go easy on me ;).  I'm assuming that I'm tying up precious resources using this approach which is causing the exponential processing time issue.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this is entity framework, I would guess you're running into the overhead of change tracking with large number of objects. There are various ways to tackle this. Google "entity framework change tracking" and perhaps "AutoDetectChangesEnabled" for some background.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to look into this.  My general logic is to take one object from the list and assign it to a domain object, save, rinse repeat.  I'm not sure why it would track changes as these are new objects.  For those objects that I'm checking if they already exist, I run the db.model.find(), then assign every value from the list object to the 'found' domain object.

Comment: Is this what you were referencing Atoms? http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with SQL Server and willing to use something outside of Entity-framework there's a bulk copy routine that might be very useful for you.  Basically what you do is to create a table in memory (its a .net object) and then add your records to that.  Once you've added all 72K records to the table then you'll all at once save that to the database.  Since this uses bulk copy functionality that's tuned for this scenario its extremely fast.

Here's a couple articles that might get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy

http://dotnetmentors.com/c-sharp/bulk-upload-into-sql-server-using-sqlbulkcopy-and-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: I appreciate this! Its going to be a routine thing to grab files and process them into this system. I'll probably stick with EF and try to write a better approach... But def going to look into what you suggested for data migrations, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This credit should really go to Atoms for pointing out the "AutoDetectChangesEnabled" reference.  I found a great article by Rick Strahl here; http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs which explains it well!

My 15 min processing just got knocked down to 45 seconds wooot!!!

Thanks!